# Is it possible to check whether these two means are statistically different?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I am building a model on loan borrowers data. It's a binary classification problem, and I want to know whether income a person has, has any effect on whether the person would default on loan. I am in a very initial phase of the development and I still don't know whether 0 or 1 in the target represents that person would default.

My initial intuition is that more the income a person has, less likely he is to default. So I divided the the data based on income into two categories: rich and poor and took the mean of the count of these values for both the categories. All the 1s add up and represent the fraction of population who let's say would default. I want to test the hypothesis that poor people are more likely to default and so their mean would be higher than that of rich. I am getting mean of 16.7% for poor and 15.1% for rich. I want to know if these are statistically different or they are just the same.

I have total of 9578 entries with poor making up 5092 of them and 4486 of them being rich. The probability of being 1 on the entire dataset is 0.160 or 16%. How can I proceed from here? What if I divide the data into 4 income categories?

Comment: Sure, you can do a proportion test. My guess is that your sample size will cause that difference to be significant at any of the usual levels (e.g. $0.05$). You have a bigger issue, though, that you are using your hypothesis that rich people default less to test if rich people default less.

Comment: @Dave Sorry I couldn't understand. Could you pls explain what do you mean "using the hypothesis that rich people default less to test if rich people default less"?

Comment: You're trying to figure out if $0$ means default or of $1$ means default. In order to do that, you are trying to figure out which group has more $0$, the rich people or the poor people. If the poor group has more $0$s, then $0$ must mean default. If the rich group has more $0$s, then $1$ must mean default. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct. I am assuming 1s mean default and then testing that with the hypothesis that poor people are more likely to default, so they should have more number of 1s. A reaffirmation. I get only a slightly larger number and then I want to know if it's significant.

Comment: And then you use that definition of $0$ and $1$ in your analysis of whether or not wealth and defaults are related...but it all comes from your assumption that wealth and defaults are realted.

Comment: You mean to say that I can only infer whether poor default more or rich once I know the actual definitions of 0 and 1 because my initial hypothesis may not be correct in real world. I can only assume one out of definition of 0,1 or the initial hypothesis but not both.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform an asymptotic Wald test on the difference or ratio of proportions.  Let $\hat{p}_\text{p}$ be the estimated proportion among the poor and let $\hat{p}_\text{r}$ be the estimated proportion of defaults among the rich.  Then

$$ 1-\Phi\Bigg(\frac{\hat{p}_\text{p}-\hat{p}_\text{r}-0}{\hat{\text{se}}}\Bigg) $$

is the one-sided upper-tailed p-value testing the hypothesis $H_0: \hat{p}_\text{p}-\hat{p}_\text{r} \le 0$ where $\hat{\text{se}}=\sqrt{\hat{p}_\text{p}(1-\hat{p}_\text{p})/n_{\text{p}} + \hat{p}_\text{r}(1-\hat{p}_\text{r})/n_{\text{r}}}$, $n_{\text{p}}$ is the number of poor subjects, and $n_{\text{r}}$ is the number of rich subjects.  You can test other hypotheses by changing the null value $0$ to a different value.  You can compare the p-value to a pre-specified $\alpha$ level to reject or not reject the null hypothesis, or you can simply report the p-value as the weight of the evidence (smaller p-value being stronger evidence against the null).  The corresponding $100(1-\alpha)\%$ confidence intervals for the unknown fixed true ${p}_\text{p}$, ${p}_\text{r}$, and ${p}_\text{p}-{p}_\text{r}$ are

$$\hat{p}_\text{p}\pm z_{1-\alpha/2}\cdot\sqrt{\hat{p}_\text{p}(1-\hat{p}_\text{p})/n_{\text{p}}} $$

$$\hat{p}_\text{r}\pm z_{1-\alpha/2}\cdot\sqrt{\hat{p}_\text{r}(1-\hat{p}_\text{r})/n_{\text{r}}} $$

$$\hat{p}_\text{p}-\hat{p}_\text{r}\pm z_{1-\alpha/2}\cdot\sqrt{\hat{p}_\text{p}(1-\hat{p}_\text{p})/n_{\text{p}} + \hat{p}_\text{r}(1-\hat{p}_\text{r})/n_{\text{r}}}. $$

Typically, 95% confidence intervals are used so $z_{1-\alpha/2}=1.96$.

For a ratio of proportions,

$$ 1-\Phi\Bigg(\frac{\text{log}\{\hat{p}_\text{p}/\hat{p}_\text{r}\}-\text{log}\{ 1\}}{\hat{\text{se}}}\Bigg) $$

is the one-sided upper-tailed p-value testing the hypothesis $H_0: \hat{p}_\text{p}/\hat{p}_\text{r} \le 1$ where $\hat{\text{se}}=\sqrt{(1-\hat{p}_\text{p})/\hat{p}_\text{p}n_{\text{p}} + (1-\hat{p}_\text{r})/\hat{p}_\text{r}n_{\text{r}}}$ is the estimated standard error of $\text{log}\{\hat{p}_\text{p}/\hat{p}_\text{r}\}$ based on the delta method (notice the subtle difference compared to before).  The corresponding $100(1-\alpha)\%$ confidence interval for the unknown fixed true ${p}_\text{p}/{p}_\text{r}$ is

$$\text{exp}\Bigg[\text{log}\{\hat{p}_\text{p}/\hat{p}_\text{r}\}\pm z_{1-\alpha/2}\cdot\sqrt{(1-\hat{p}_\text{p})/\hat{p}_\text{p}n_{\text{p}} + (1-\hat{p}_\text{r})/\hat{p}_\text{r}n_{\text{r}}}\Bigg]$$

Based on the point estimates you have provided, even if they are statistically significantly different, it may not be meaningfully different in terms of the effect size (16.7% vs 15.1%).

I'm guessing the data you have collected is not from a randomized trial.  The inference above is useful for determining association between wealth and loan default.  In order to make a causal connection we must assume no unmeasured confounders, meaning we must assume there are no other customer characteristics that drive loan defaults that are also associated with wealth.  As an example, one could posit that being rich or poor has nothing  to do with loan defaults and that it is actually a different factor that is responsible.  This other factor just happens to be more prevalent among poor people than among rich people, and so it only looks like wealth (or lack there of) is responsible for defaulting.  If you wanted to adjust for potential confounders you can construct inverse-probability-weights, but this is a much more complex topic.